# How tall could bamboo grow

Tags: science-based, flora

How tall could a bamboo-like (i.e hollow with nodes) tree be ? It should be at very least 1.5m of diameter and walls no more than 20cm thick. The internodes should be 2 to 5 meter long. I think it would need rhizomes etc and grow like bamboo does but you can change whatever you want. Something else I also would like to know is how fast would it grow?

Note that I'm asking only for the resistance to mecanical stresses like tree's own  weight or wind even though the first culms would probably be shorter and with several ones wind is less of an issue.

Comment: Find the measurements of today's tallest bamboo and scale just scale it up.  Remember: fiction doesn't need to be factual, it just needs to be *reasonable*.

Comment: What research did you do? What is preventing you from finding the answer to this yourself?

Comment: @dot_spot stack exchange code of conduct frowns on “you could search for that” replies. https://stackoverflow.com/conduct If it is already on the exchange then close as duplicate. If not, then it’s a legit question as SE seeks to be a place where direct questions break info out from deeper content.

Comment: This is answered on other Stack Exchanges like biology and gardening. Also, there are a lot of different species of bamboo with a whole world of different properties between them. Google is your best friend in this case

Comment: No they don't answer my question the only thing I found is how tall real bamboo can grow but I want a bamboo tree which doesn't appear to exist IRL.

Comment: Probably 400 feet max. After that you can't get water up to the top anymore due to gravity. You can check the questions on how call can a tree grow for a closer or more accurate answer.

Comment: @Jean-Abdel Thats why they told you to scale it up. It doesn't exist naturally. So take a real world example that is very close to what you want (in terms of diameter and thickness ratio). Then just scale it up until you have what you wanted. Then use that scaling on the height and see how tall it is.

Comment: If it gets _too_ big, Pandazilla will see it and eat it.

Comment: @SRM I wasn't aware that me asking about their research and the actual problem they encountered that brought them to ask on here was a breach of conduct; when checking the [help-center](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) these things are listed in the second section (titled: *General guidelines for all questions*)

Comment: @SRM also please consider using the auto-complete feature or copy-paste usernames when @-ing to prevent mistyping. Mistyped names will not only not notify the addressed user, they can also convey the feeling that the mistyper does not consider the other conversation partner an equal - as they seemingly neither care about addressing them correctly, nor if they get notified

Comment: @dot-sp0t sorry about the misspelling. I wish more fonts would put the slash on zeroes for disambiguation. As for the other... it wasn’t your first question that bothered me. It was the second. The find-it-yourself meme is pretty deep on the SEs and does harm, in my observation. I may be over sensitive in pushing back on it.

Comment: @Jean-Abdel Sorry for the off-topic tangent in this thread. I did try to work on your question, but it’s far outside my area of expertise, and I didn’t find anything helpful.

Comment: @Shadowzee It's not as simple as that though. Square-cubed law applies to size, limited by material strength. Transport of nutrients from the root system is also limited by height etc.

Answer (score 4):

## Bamboo is strong so the limit is not strength

Wood in general is pretty strong in tension and compression. Furthermore, it is light so as it gets taller it isn't putting too much stress on itself. As long as the bamboo can increase the radius of its trunk, it can get very tall. Especially if it grows in dense thickets, the protection of other nearby bamboo stalks would help it to survive winds.

On the other hand, bamboo is limited, like all trees, by the [mechanics of water transportation](https://www.nature.com/articles/nature02417). It is hard to move water straight upwards. So, like other trees, bamboo would be limited to about 120-130 meters of maximum height.